# How to update postgreSQL auto incremental field from SAS DI Table Loader

Tags: postgresql, sas, etl

I'm new to SAS and PostGreSQL, and I currently working on migrating SAS data to PostGreSQL.
I have problem when I tried to insert data into PostGreSQL, where there are a auto-incremental column "Id" in the table.
I using SAS DI, create node SourceTable -> Extract -> Table Loader -> TargetTable.
I ignore map TagetTable.Id cause this is an auto-incremental column.
I got error said Id cannot be Null

Then I tried use NextVal("Id") under Id Expression, and I got error "Function NEXTVAL could not be located"

I tried to set the "Is Nullable" in SAS to true for "Id", but still get error cannot be Null.

May I know how can I do this?

Other than the Id, I also have problem with the timestamp, timestamp should generate by using PostGreSQL...

Answer (score 0):

Use a 2-step process:

1. Import the data into a *staging* table, which matches exactly the schema of the source
2. Populate the final table from the staging table

The reason this makes it easier is the first battle is getting the data into Postgres, but once you've done that you have the full power of Postgres's SQL available for you to create the data you need for the final table, including using multiple queries to get the job done if required.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. The problem is I have quite a lot tables need to ETL to Postgres... So what I going to do is, in the ETL I use node to do the data massaging and final use user written code to insert into Postgres so avoid the Id error.